# Fitting distribution for count data

Tags: goodness-of-fit, count-data, overfitting, curve-fitting, zero-inflation

I am interested to fit distribution to the count data presented as histogram below:

[image: Histogram of count data]

Is there a way to understand what is the most likely distribution of the data without apriori hypothesizing the distribution?

Following, let's say I suspect the data to be distributed according to zero-inflated Poisson distribution. If I don't have any explanatory variables, is the right way to model it would be:

```
library(pscl)
fm_zip <- zeroinfl(span$lifespan ~1, data = counts)
```

**EDIT:**

After fitting negaitve binomial zero-inflated model (lifespan ~1, ) the following model is reached (visualized with rootograms; countreg package):
[image]

There seems to be a systematic overestimation in the first part of the histogram (x<20), and underestimation in the second part.

- Is there a way to improve the fit without adding new explanatory variable?
- Does it make sense to add dummy variable that indicates whether X>20 as explanatory variable?

Comment: What are your estimates for the mean and variance (assuming zero-inflated poisson)?

Comment: Your approach seems a good starting point. I might be a bit worried about the slight piling up at higher counts. If you get a poor fit try the negative binomial of which Poisson is a special case. The vignette for pscl is a mine of useful information.

Comment: "The most likely distribution" is the one that assigns probability $k/n$ to the number $x$ when $x$ has appeared $k$ times in a dataset of $n$ values. In other words, it's exactly the *empirical distribution* of the data. This illustrates a classic trade-off: if you're willing to assume little or nothing about the data-generation process, then what you can infer from the data is equally limited.

Comment: @ilanman the mean is 6.31 and standard deviation is 11.39. Thanks!